# c# Split image for mouse click

Tags: c#

Basically, I am creating a simple form application for use in the game of 501 darts. My idea was to use an image of a darts board so the user can click where they hit on the board (example - they throw a 16, they click 16 on the dart board and this takes 16 from the total score)

My question - Can I use just one image and make it so a click in a certain location changes the value? So clicking anywhere in the 16 removes a value of 16, etc. I don't think this is possible, but I thought it was worth asking.

Or is the only way to do this separately create an image for each number and put them together to form an image of a dart board?

Thanks!

Comment: A different route would be to catch all click events on your form, parse the click location and handle appropriately. It does require some calculations to find out where the user clicked and where a "16" is.. for example. Brute force but way simpler than OCR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate a second image from the dartboard image, apply unique colors to each scoring zone.  When a user clicks on the dartboard image, you get the X,Y position and do a pixel lookup on the second image.  Compare the pixel color with a score table.

Using unique colors would require a lookup table like `Score -= Table[pixel[x][y]]` whereas you could also directly apply the score to a color channel and the pixel lookup would have your score.  Such as: `Score -= pixel[x][y].red`

---

Below is a C# Winform program I quickly prototyped in SharpDevelop targeting .NET 4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PictureClicker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        Bitmap dartboard;
        Bitmap scoreboard;

        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
            dartboard = new Bitmap("dartboard.bmp");
            scoreboard = new Bitmap("scoreboard.bmp");
        }
        void MainFormPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(dartboard, 0, 0);
        }
        void MainFormMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int score = scoreboard.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToArgb(); // Convert pixel to 32-bit representation to facilitate comparison

            // Lookup table
            if (score == Color.Red.ToArgb()) RecordScore(16); // Red FF0000
            else if (score == Color.Lime.ToArgb()) RecordScore(8); // Green 00FF00
            else if (score == Color.Blue.ToArgb()) RecordScore(4); // Blue 0000FF
            else if (score == Color.Yellow.ToArgb()) RecordScore(2); // Yellow FFFF00
            else if (score == Color.Magenta.ToArgb()) RecordScore(1); // Purple (Magenta) FF00FF
            else if (score == Color.Cyan.ToArgb()) RecordScore(100); // Cyan 00FFFF
            else
                Debug.WriteLine("Unknown Score");
        }

        void RecordScore(int _score)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hit: " + _score.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Dartboard image:
[image: Dartboard]

Scoreboard image:
[image: Scoreboard]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to use the [Tesseract](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)  optical character recognition. But remember, a dart board only has numbers on the outside of the board, so determining what the score is on each of the inside tiles may be difficult.